# Select all elements except one and it's children in jQuery not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is simple enough.  I want to make the entire section clickable except the span and everything underneath because I want the link to redirect elsewhere.

```
<section id="id" class="message">
 <div class="message_body">
  <font color="color">text</font>
   <span style="style">
      <a href="url">
        <img src="linktoimage"></img>
      </a>
   </span>
   <br></br>
   <text name="message_comment" id="message_comment">message</text>
 </div>
</section>
```

I've tried the following:

```
$('.message:not(span)').click(function() {
  window.location.href = "url";
});
```

and

```
$(".message").not("span").click(function() {
  window.location.href = "url";
});
```

The behavior is correct in both Chrome and Firefox. But in Safari, the a href link does not work. It is treated as a link when rendered in html, but when you click on it the jQuery behavior of treating the entire class kicks in, as if it ignores the 'not span'. Is there anyway to rewrite this to work in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Rather than excluding the span from the click, target a click handler on the span, and cancel the event.

Comment: The selector `'.message:not(span)'` is saying "Do not select `<span class="message">`" It is not looking at the children....

Comment: Ah ok, I need to learn a little more about selectors in jQuery.  For some reason it still worked lol! Thank you epascarello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the span so that if they click it, the click event will not continue to bubble up.

```js
$('.message').on('click', function(){
  console.log( 'yeah!' );
});

$('.message span').on('click', function (e) {
  console.log( 'denied!' );
  //stop the event from bubbling up out of the span to the parent elements
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="message">
  <span>Click Me!</span>
  <div>Other Stuff</div>
</div>
```